# C++11 - How to use a priority_queue with a vector of shared pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr, priority-queue

I have a `priority queue` inside my class, like this:

```
    class Foo
    {
    public:
        //public methods...
    private:
        std::priority_queue<Obj, std::vector<Obj>, object_less> foo_queue;

        //private methods and members...
    }
```

And I've been using the `emplace()` method to insert objects inside my `priority_queue`, like this:

```
void Foo::add( ... ) {
    foo_queue.emplace(var1, var2);
}
```

And that will call the constructor of `Obj(var1,var2)` and insert it into the `priority queue`.

But now, I need to have access to the `std::vector<Obj>` from outside. From my `Obj` objects.

Something like creating an `Foo object`, and changing member that lives inside an object on the `priority_queue`:

```
Foo myFoo; // <-- this is where the priority_queue is!

Obj myObj(1); //Creating an object that has some member with value '1'

myFoo.add(myObj); //This will add the object to the priority_queue via emplace (actually it is creating a new object...and not using that one)

myObj.m_member = 2; //HERE WON'T WORK!!! And now I want to change some value on my Obj to '2'. It won't work, because the object that lives inside the priority_queue is different from this one!
```

**So, I was thinking of :**

- Instead of using the `emplace` method, use the `push` (maybe the push won't create a new object)
- Changing the `priority_queue` to, instead of having a vector of objects `std::vector<Obj>` having a vector of shared pointers, so I can have access to the `Obj` that it is inside of the `priority_queue` from outside..as shown above.

**QUESTION:**

Do you think this is a good idea? I'm a newbie in smart_pointers.. I don't know if there is an easier solution for this.

How can I use a priority_queue with a vector of shared_pointers?
Anyone knows a simple example I can follow?

Something like this:

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Obj>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obj>>, object_less> foo_queue;
```

And then hopefully, I can execute:

```
Foo myFoo;
Obj myObj(1);
myFoo.add(myObj);
myObj.m_member = 2; //<--Now the m_member should be 2 inside the priority_queue.. is this "possible"?
```

Comment: `push` instead of `emplace` will not solve your problem. The solution with `shared_ptr` "works", but it is bad design. Why does the object live inside the class and the priority queue at the same time? Why can't the class go through the queue instead?

Comment: I create an object (Obj), and then I want to insert it into my priority_queue. Created like this so that other modules will only use a simple interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having a priority queue of shared_ptrs. The one thing you'll need to look out for is the comparison. `priority_queue` needs a comparison, of course, and by default it uses `operator <`. But that operator, on shared_ptrs, compares the pointers themselves instead of the pointed-to objects. You'll need to pass a custom comparator to the priority queue which operates on the objects themselves. Luckily it looks like you're already using a custom comparator, so the compiler will yell at you if you forget to do that (though the error message may be *exceedingly* arcane).

One other caveat: If you modify the object in a way that affects its ordering within the priority queue, stuff *will* go wrong. The only way to do this through the `priority_queue` interface is to remove the element from the queue, change it, and re-add it.